# What is the best practice for adding records to a production DB once deployed to a VPS?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I just deployed my rails app to a Linode VPS, and was wondering what would be the best way of adding records to the DB.

I have tables such as Categories, which I'd like to populate.

I thought of the Taps gem, using a csv, or an sql dump file.

I'd like to know if there are any tools out there for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this puporse there are the so called seed file which is default in:

```
db/seeds.rb
```

You can add entries here ( there is an example in the seed file ), which you can generate after deployment with a rake task:

```
rake db:seed
```

You probably are using bundler as well, so use:

```
bundle exec rake db:seed
```

**In case of large number of seeds** you can always create multiple files, see [this blogpost about handling large seed files](http://dev.mensfeld.pl/2011/10/handling-large-seed-files-in-ruby-on-rails/).

However, **if** you are in a state, where **the already existing data in the app is crucial** and you are changing servers or database drivers you wanna take a look on [yaml_db gem](https://github.com/ludicast/yaml_db) which gives a nice method to abstract the existing data away from your actual db driver and export it into a .yaml file which you can import later back e.g.: after deploying on a new server.

See [Railscast - #179](http://railscasts.com/episodes/179-seed-data) about seeding.

Comment: I thought about seeding, but what if I have thousands of records? I do for another model

Comment: Updated my answer. You wanna stay at seeding, cause it is an object relational model solution for this, so you got no problem if you wanna swtich between database drivers.

Answer (score 0):

The rails way would be to use seed data in db/seeds.rb and then populate it by using `rake db:seed`.

You could also use a sql dump file and restore by issueing `mysql -u <user> -p <database_name> < <mysql_dump_file>`

Answer (score 0):

The [Easy Reference Data](https://github.com/AbleTech/easy_reference_data) gem is similar to db:seed, but will update records if entries already exist. It also has easy integration with Capistrano.

Full disclosure: The company I work for developed the gem.